# Unable to perform FTP upload from Visual Studio 2012 (Access is denied)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a weird problem. I can not do an ftp publish via Visual Studio 2012.

It is set as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the connection is validated.

However, for each file I get the following error when publishing:

```
Unable to add 'somefile.aspx' to the Web site.  somefile.aspx: Access is denied (550).
```

All the stuff I've seen points to permissions errors, but I can upload via FileZilla fine.

Comment: check if your files are marked as read only

Comment: Nope - they're not read only.

Comment: What kind of credentials are you using?  Local or domain?  What are the ACLs on the FTP folder?  Just an FYI if your FTP server is encrypted with FTPS on IIS (as it should be), the internal FTP client within Visual Studio does not support it.  Until MSFT gets with the program and joins the modern era when it comes to a feature such as this, you'll have to leverage FileZilla.

Comment: It's a hosted server, so just straight ftp access to the wwwroot directory. (Unfortunately this means I can't see the ACLs. The host has tweaked the security, and I now get Can't connect to 'xyz' on port 21. Check the server name and proxy settings.

Comment: At this point I would recommend calling your hosting company as they may have tweaked something on their end.  When it comes to configurations its not uncommon for each hosting company to have their own policy for how processes such as this are configured.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my AV package interfering with it. For some reason it was happy for FTP via FileZilla, but not from Visual Studio. Disabled AV and it uploaded fine.